# SetInterval several elements at the same time Jquery

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have this code, It appends comments after clicking on comment button. (the php processes via other function)....

I want to simulate that every comment was posted at certain time, and the set interval after a while work independently with each `li` appendend.

**PROBLEM**

In the snippet it is shown that if I post a  comment set interval works with it to show `how long time ago` it was posted (need format but it has the idea).

The problem is that anytime I post a new comment, set intervals reloads all the previous times and shows the same results for all the comments.

```js
$('.comment').on('click', function(){
        timeIni=$.now();

          comment=$(".textarea").val();
            $("#comments").append("<li data-t='"+timeIni+"'>"+comment+" <span>1s</span>"+"</li>");
            
            $(".textarea").val("");
        
      //adding the time to looks like 
       /* */ setInterval(function(){ 
            time=$.now();
          tempo="time: "+time;
             $("#comments span").text(tempo);
                           }, 2000); 
         
 


        });
```

```css
textarea{
height:30px;
width:200px;
border:1px solid red;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


     <ul id="comments"></ul>

      <textarea class=textarea></textarea>
       <input type=submit class="comment" value='comment' />
```

I want every comments shows its own time interval, according with the time it was posted.

Other try using `.each()`

https://jsfiddle.net/s8650s18/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variables with a keyword such as var, let, const otherwise the variable becomes global. All boils down to a scoping issue.

```
let timeIni = Number($.now());
```

Here is the fiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/s8650s18/22/

Comment: Omg you are a genius. thank you very much!! I had this issue for ages!! of course declaring variables!